# RANGE BETWEEN function with Timestamp values in SQL Impala

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I am trying to calculate a moving number of events (impressions) that happen per minute. How can I use the range between function with timestamp values to define the 1-minute interval?

I have something like this:

```
count(impression) over (partition by user 
                        ORDER BY trunc(cast(entrytime as TIMESTAMP), "MI") 
                        RANGE BETWEEN interval 1 minutes Preceding 
                        and interval 1 minutes Following) as densityperminute
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: when you say it doesn't work..do you mean you get an error? if so, post the error message as well.

Comment: `RANGE` probably allows only `unbounded`, but not `n` (I don't know if any SQL dialect actually supports it, would be really hard to implement).

Comment: the error message I get is the following: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 5:undefined: ...ETWEEN interval 1 minutes Preceding and interval 1 min... ^ Encountered: PRECEDING Expected: + CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not supported, unfortunately. From the documentation for 6.1:

> Currently, Impala supports only some combinations of arguments to the
>   RANGE clause:
>
> - RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW (the default when
>     ORDER BY is specified and the window clause is omitted)
> - RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
> - RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING

[Source](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_analytic_functions.html#window_clause)

(Forgive me answering an old question, but I'm currently looking into this for a school project and this came up in my search!)